# extreme points of unit balls on $L_1(\mu)$

Tags: functional-analysis

I wanna show that for a measure space $(X, \mu)$, the set of extreme points of the unit ball of $L_1(\mu)$ equals the set of characteristic functions of atoms of $\mu$ multiplied by a suitable constant(to guarantee that the norm is 1).

I tried to show followings:
1) $f\in L_1(\mu)$, and if there are two disjoints subsets $A, B$ of $X$ with $A\cup B=X$ and $\int_A |f|d\mu>0, \int_B |f|d\mu>0$, then $f$ is not an extreme point of $L_1(\mu)$.

2)If there are no such pairs of $A, B$, then $f$ is a constant multiple of a characteristic function of an atom.

But it is hard to show 2). Is there any hints for this approach or other nice way to prove the original question?

Answer (score 3):

$(\mathcal{T}1)$ Every measurable function is constant on atoms.

Proof:
consider atom $A$ and function $f$ that isn't constant on $A$.There is a value $r\in \mathbb{R}$, such that $\mu(f^{-1}((-\infty,r)))>0\land \mu(f^{-1}([r,+\infty)))>0$. Those two sets are division of an atom and both have positive measure - contradiction. QED.

Conclusion: define $X_f:=\{x\in X:f(x)\neq 0\}$. If $\int_{X_f}fd\mu=1$, then every atom $A\subset X_f$ has finite measure. From now on I will consider only those.

By definition $X_f$ is an atom iff for any $A\subset X_f$ $A\cong\emptyset\lor A\cong X_f$, but it is also equivalent to statement: $$(*)\forall A\subset X_f:\int_A|f|d\mu=\int_{\emptyset}|f|d\mu\lor \int_A|f|d\mu=\int_{X_f}|f|d\mu$$

As you have noticed, all extreme points (if any) should be located on sphere, and existence of division $A,B$ such that $\int_A |f|d\mu>0, \int_B |f|d\mu>0$ is **sufficient** for $f$ to not be an extreme point (take $g_1:=\frac{1}{\mu(A)}\chi_Af$ and $g_2:=\frac{1}{\mu(B)}\chi_Bf$ then $f=\mu(A)g_1+\mu(B)g_2$, and $g_1\in \mathbb{S}, g_2\in \mathbb{S}$). In the light of (*) it could be stated: if $X_f$ is not atomic then $f$ is not an extreme point. Lets show that it is **necessary** too:

$(\mathcal{T}2)$ If $X_f$ is atomic, then $f$ is an extreme point.

Proof:
Suppose, that $f$ is not an extreme point: $$\exists{a\in (0,1)}\ \exists{g,h\in \mathbb{B}\setminus \{f\}}: f\cong ag+(1-a)h$$

It is clear, that $X_f\setminus (X_g \cup X_h)\cong \emptyset$ and in restriction to $X\setminus X_f$, $ag$ and $(1-a)h$ will cancel out:
$$ (ag+(1-a)h)\restriction_{X\setminus X_f}\cong 0=f\restriction_{X\setminus X_f}$$
but then
$$ (**)ag+(1-a)h\cong \chi_{X_f}(ag+(1-a)h)=a\chi_{X_f}g+(1-a)\chi_{X_f}h$$
 Because of $(\mathcal{T}1)$ functions $f,g$, and $h$ have to be (a.e.) constant within $X_f$:
$$(***)
\left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       g\restriction_{X_f}\cong uf\restriction_{X_f} \\
       h\restriction_{X_f}\cong vf\restriction_{X_f}
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$
for some $u,v\in [-1,1)$ ($u,v\neq 1$ because $g,h \neq f$). From $(**)$ and $(***)$:
$$ag+(1-a)h\cong a\chi_{X_f}uf+(1-a)\chi_{X_f}vf$$
$$ \chi_{X_f}f=f$$
$$ag+(1-a)h\cong auf+(1-a)vf\cong f$$
That boils down to one variable case: $1=au+(1-a)v$. There are no $u,v\in [-1,1)$ that satisfy this equation - contradiction.

Conclusion: $f$ is an extreme point. QED.

Notation:

1. $\chi_{\square}$ is characteristic function of the set $\square$
2. $\mathbb{B}=\{f:X\to \mathbb{R}| f-measurable \land \int_{X}|f|d\mu\le 1\}$ is closed unit ball centered in constant zero function.
3. $\mathbb{S}=\{f\in\mathbb{B}|\int_{X}|f|d\mu=1\}$ is unit sphere.
4. $A\cong B$, $f\cong g$ means that $\mu(A\setminus B)+\mu(B\setminus A)=0$ and $\mu(\{x:f(x)\neq g(x)\})=0$ respectively.

Comment: Thank you very much first! I have a question. Why $f=ag+(1-a)h$ a.e. implies symmetric difference of $X_f$ and $X_g\cup X_h$ are measure zero?

Comment: I understand that $X_f\setminus X_g\cup X_h$ is an empty set, but how about $X_g\cup X_h \setminus X_f$? Even if $ag+(1-a)h=0$ on a set of positive measure, I cannot find any contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. $X_g\cup X_h\setminus X_f$ can be positive indeed. I have fixed this error. Answer is a bit more clunky now, but it should be correct.

Comment: It is really an amazing proof! Thank you.